# Can you help me identify this manufacturer's logo on this component

Tags: diodes, identification, vintage

Stylized S logo that I cannot find any information on. The model of this stud mount diode is 240E10RTC. It measures 45 mm in width has 20 mm threaded end[image: S LOGO STUD MOUNT DIODE]

Comment: maybe you can take a guess at the country of manufacturing?

Comment: top of my head there's Semikron (Germany) and Semtech (USA, I guess) as companies that produce discrete diodes like that one.

Comment: Is it exactly 45mm across the flats?  Or 1 3/4 inches (44.45mm) ?  Might help eliminate country of origin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It could be a [Standard Rectifier Corporation](https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_ca/C0392181) 240E10,R. It appears [in this June 1960 catalog](https://worldradiohistory.com/hd2/IDX-Site-Technical/Engineering-General/Archive-Tele-Tech-IDX/IDX/60s/Electronic-Industires-1960-06-OCR-Page-0197.pdf). The company seems to be defunct: it was registered in 1960 and then its registration was surrendered in 1964.

[image]

I also found a [tabulation](https://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/Databooks/Semicond/_contents/D.A.T.A.%27s%20Semiconductor%20Diode%20and%20Rectifier%201961.pdf) (also from 1961) which lists its characteristics on page 35 (pdf page 38).

[image]

Comment: The company logo in the datasheet corner does not match the logo on the diode. Are you sure this is the right company for the logo?

Comment: @Justme No, I'm not positive. But it's not a datasheet and doesn't claim to be issued by the manufacturer of the part. It's a tabulation, more like a catalog. This was common in the 60s.

Comment: So how do you know it even is the manufacturer of the part? There can be dozens of manufacturers for a standard part number.

Comment: @Justme Quite true, like I said, I'm not positive.

Answer (score 23):

As TypeIA suspected, this is a Standard Rectifier Corporation diode. The logo below is from [Electronics](https://worldradiohistory.com/Archive-Electronics/60s/61/Electronics-1961-02-03.pdf), Feb 3, 1961, page 81.

[image: Standard Rectifier Corporation logo.]

Comment: TWX, wow, that brings back memories.